# page.onload function not running

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started making my first website, and this is the first **REAL** problem that I have run into. I'm trying to make "Sign in" and "Sign up" buttons that automatically change their text if the user is logged in. To do it, I'm using Javascript to read the localStorage username value, check if it equals null, and then set both button's .innerHTML based on that. The problem? My Javascript won't run. Here's the HTML/Javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Phyre-Home</title>
<link href="Phyre-Home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="javascript">
page.onload function{
var profile = document.getElementById("Profile");
var signout = document.getElementById("SignUpOut");
var username = localStorage.getItem('phyreUsername');
if(username == null) {
profile.innerHTML = "Sign in";
signout.innerHTML = "Sign up";
}else{
profile.innerHTML = username;
signout.innerHTML = "Sign out";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img src="PhyreSiteHeader.bmp" alt="Phyre">
<button id="SignUpOut"></button>
<button id="Profile"></button>
<h1 style="display:none">Fire</h1>
<script language="javascript">

</script>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><b>Home</b></li>
<li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/profile">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/games">Games</a></li>
<li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/chat">Chat</a></li>
<li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/videos">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<aside>
<h1><b>Page Nav</b><br></h1>
<p><i>This page does not have its own, separate navigation section. Sorry.</i></p>
<h1><b>Ads</b><br></h1>

</aside>
<article>

</article>
</body>
</html>
```

...And here's the CSS, just in case it matters:

```
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, main, nav, section, summary {
display:block;
}
header:img{
max-width:90%;
}
body{
background-color:rgb(75, 75, 75);
margin:0px;
font-family:times new roman, serif;
}
header{
width:100%;
float:top;
}
#SignUpOut{
position:absolute;
top:0%;
right:0%;
}
#Profile{
position:absolute;
top:0%;
right:7.5em;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
font-family:AR BLANCA, times new roman, serif;
}
ul{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li{
float:left;
width:20%;
font-size:large;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgb(187, 15, 23);
box-sizing:border-box;
background-color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
border-width:2px;
margin-bottom:0.5%;
}
aside{
float:left;
width:20%;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgb(187, 15, 23);
box-sizing:border-box;
background-color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
border-width:3.5px;
padding:0.5%;
margin-right:0.5%;
}
article{
float:right;
width:79.5%;
border-style:solid;
border-color:rgb(187, 15, 23);
box-sizing:border-box;
background-color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
border-width:3.5px;
padding:0.5%;
}
```

The culprit is the first Javascript section. Please help if you can, I'm pretty new to HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript.

P.S. I don't have a domain or anything yet, so none of the links are valid.

Comment: It is not `page` it is `window` and should be like `window.onload = function(){ ...`

Comment: your Javascript is a bit broken, like `page.onload function{` this is not even syntactically valid. Open your javascript console and check the errors one by one. It seems at this point your problem is more simple than the inner logic.

Comment: "My Javascript won't run."  What happens?

Comment: Alright @Phyremaster, if you look down below, I have completely created your example in `jsbin` and made an end-to-end working example for you, that demonstrates everything you are asking and need to do to make it work. You can see it here, as well; `http://jsbin.com/xevuz/1` and the code used to create it is here `http://jsbin.com/xevuz/1/edit` - please ask me any questions you have.

Comment: Alright, I have now updated my question with a complete, verbose explanation of the problem, as well as a working demo for two different scenarios, screen shots to help you see the differences, and code samples. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Omg I feel so stupid! All I did wrong was use the wrong word! Sorry for posting such a dumb question. Thanks, everyone, for your help!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, "Profile" refers to the button. I'll right the code for the buttons later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no such thing as `page`, you probably want `window`

```
window.onload = function() {...
```

or just drop the onload handler and move the script to the bottom, right before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `page` is not a JavaScript variable.

You could do something like

```
function myLoadFunction() {
    ...
}
```

then

```
<body onload="myLoadFunction()">
...
</body>
```

---

Alternatively you can use `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function () {
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made you a completely working example here, that does everything you are asking, you may simply click this link to see it in action. You may click the second link in order to see the code and dissect it a bit.

## [Working Sample (with username)](http://jsbin.com/xevuz/1/)

> Just click the link to see it work.

[image]

## [Working Sample (without username)](http://jsbin.com/sipuy/1/)

> Just click the link to see it work.

[image]

## [Working Sample (Code)](http://jsbin.com/xevuz/1/edit)

> Just click the link, then click `Run with JS` to see it work.
>   [image]

Now that I have shown you a completely working solution, allow me to explain why it works.

- You do not appear to be using any sort of external library, this means that there is really nothing running overhead to try and help manage when these events fire and such.
- You did not declare any kind of `id` on the elements you were trying to fetch

To demonstrate this, I cite your original code;

```
var profile = document.getElementById("Profile");
```

Which was assumed to be functioning on the following `<a>` tag.

```
<li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/profile">Profile</a></li>
```

The problem here is that `document.getElementById` actually needs an `id` to get by. This is remedied by ammending the `<a>` tag with an `id`, like this.

```
<li><a id="Profile" href="www.phyregaming.com/profile">Profile</a></li>
```

The next part of the problem is that you needed this code to run only after the page had loaded. But because you're running just normal javascript, it will run in the order it is seen - unless wrapped inside of a function. Because `page.onload` is not a valid function, your javascript simply threw an error, and since `page.onload` is not a real function, it didn't quite understand what its own problem was, so it didn't give you any really useful information.

I fixed this by first wrapping your code in a function, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ready() {
      // your javascript code here
   }
</script>
```

What this meant is that when the page hit that part, it **created** the function, but it did not **run** it.

Then you needed to **run** the function, but only once the other parts of the page were ready. We did this using the `onload` attribute of the `<body>` tag, like this;

```
<body onload="ready()">
```

And that is really all there is to it! From there it was just a matter of assigning the `id` attributes where needed, and doing a little bit of housekeeping to the HTML and CSS.

I made some changes to help your sample run a bit better, most noticed is that I removed this part of your `CSS`

```
#Profile { position: absolute; top: 0%; right: 7.5em; }
```

I am not sure if you need it to be positioned like that, but from what it looked like, you wanted to make sure that the *`Profile`* section is also where the user finds the **`Login`** and **`Logout`** buttons. I accommodated by moving the `<li>` that contained those elements to the last ones in the list, this will ensure they are always rendered in the upper right part of the page, for this example.

The first one is just a sample showing how to run the code when the page is loaded. The second shows where you would put your actual code, but I do not know what your specific javascript is aiming to accomplish, so I commented it out.

Here is the complete working code.

You can remove the line `localStorage.setItem("phyreUsername", "Ciel");` or comment it out, to see how the behavior changes based on whether or not a `username` is found.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function ready(){
            // comment this line out to test different behaviors         
            localStorage.setItem("phyreUsername", "Ciel");  
            var username = localStorage.getItem("phyreUsername");

              var profile = document.getElementById("SignIn");
              var signout = document.getElementById("SignUpOut");

              if (username == null) {
                  profile.innerHTML = "Sign in";
                  signout.innerHTML = "Sign up"; 
              } else {
                  profile.innerHTML = username;
                  signout.innerHTML = "Sign out";
              }
          }
       </script>
</head>

<body onload="ready()">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><b>Home</b></li>
            <li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/games">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/chat">Chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.phyregaming.com/videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="www.phyregaming.com/profile" id="SignIn">Sign In</a>
              <a href="www.phyregaming.com/signout" id="SignUpOut">Sign Up</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside>
        <h1>
          <b>Page Nav</b>
        </h1>
        <p style="font-style: italic">This page does not have its own, separate navigation section. Sorry.</p>
        <h1>Ads</h1>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
article, aside, figure, figcaption, footer, header, main, nav, section, summary {
    display:block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid rgb(187,15,23) 2px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
body {
    background-color:rgb(75, 75, 75);
    margin:0px;
    font-family:times new roman, serif;
}
header {
    width:100%;
    float:top;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

aside {
  float:left;
    width:20%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgb(187, 15, 23);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
    border-width:3.5px;
    padding:0.5%;
    margin-right:0.5%;
}

article {
    float:right;
    width:79.5%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:rgb(187, 15, 23);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
    border-width:3.5px;
    padding:0.5%;
}
```

I hope that this gives you enough information to really start making some headway. If you have further questions, please ask.

Comment: So why the down vote this time? It literally answers the poster's question __verbatim__ in explicit, verbose detail with examples, proof, explanations, and concrete use case scenario...

Comment: It's a great answer, and you really put some effort into it, but it's a really basic question, and the OP is using `page.onload` instead of `window.onload`, that's the only issue. There **are** elements matching the ID's, and the OP's code works when just using `window.onload`, obviously as there is no `page.onload`, so this long detailed answer can be summed up in one line, *:use `window.onload`:*

Comment: ... No it doesn't. He said he is new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. His post does not have matching ids, and doesn't work using `window.onload`. Just see for yourself - http://i.imgur.com/ihMLoPG.jpg

Comment: The only references he gives are to the buttons, not the links as he was requesting. But whatever, I'm done.

Comment: and to add, `buttons` don't have a native functionality until you wire it - and he doesn't even have them within a form. The OP claimed they are new to javascript, css, and html. It doesn't matter how you slice it, to make their code __work__, it is more than just saying `window.onload` - he's going to have to understand how to wire events to DOM elements, or how to wire them elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think you're getting it, there are two buttons, both with ID's that match the javascript, then the OP checks localStorage for a username, if the username exists, set the buttons text to something, if the username doesn't exist set the buttons text to something else. You've completely changed everything to something else ?

Comment: Even if that is true, shouldn't that be up to him to decide? I provided an answer that accomplishes the requested goal, and explained in detail why it does. This isn't Star Wars where we have to charge by the laser. _"Hold your post. There's a lot of letters in it."_ My frustration stems from how down vote happy people on SO are, when it's so unnecessary. There are at least 6 different ways to answer this question, down voting those that are not yours just creates a system where it's not worth time to even bother trying to help people - which is this community is starting to make me feel.

Comment: If the user goes with your solution, yes, it will perform the immediate, instantly request solution in one line. Why does it do that? The user made it obvious that they are new to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Is there actual damage done by elaborating why an answer works? What purpose is served by hitting my points just because I use more words than you're comfortable scrolling past your screen? If he doesn't want to read it, he won't. If he does, then maybe he'll learn something new.

Comment: And I did not change that much - the user explicitly stated they were _new to javascript, HTML, and CSS_ and were using a layout that was clearly going to be frustrating. I noted the line I removed in my post, and why I removed it. Any of us that have worked in these languages long enough know certain pitfalls and frustrations that come with some techniques. Is there physical harm being done by pointing them out? Why were you even required to read my post? What purpose is even served by this whole stupid "down vote" system? Reserve it for people giving WRONG data, not data you dislike.

Comment: Besides, it is not like I can do anything now. It tells me I need more reputation to even edit the post. I could not update it even if I wanted to.

Comment: In any event, I am sorry. I do not want to cause trouble. I am just exhausted, and saw this post and had an answer. I recently had an irritating fight with someone trailing my topics and down voting them spitefully, and it has left me on edge. I apologize. But I don't have the ability to even so much as edit my post now anyway.

Comment: @adeneo hey man, if we can open up a chat session or something so I can apologize appropriately, I'll explain myself better. I am really sorry for over-reacting. How can I do that?

Comment: There's no need to apologize to me, I don't really care what you post, if you have an answer feel free to post it, as I said it's a good answer that you put some effort into, so just keep it up and don't mind the haters, some people will always downvote, I get downvotes all the time, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55732/discussion-between-ciel-and-adeneo).

Comment: Anyway, since you would not respond to my apology in private, I will do it in public. I am very sorry for my over-reaction and snappy critique of your down vote. My last week was an absolute hell, and you were merely an easy target to get angry at. It was uncalled for, it was unprofessional, it was wrong. Your answer was plenty sufficient, I also feel my answer accomplishes the OP's goals. But I should not have acted how I did.